# Resque Optimisation on Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra, resque

I'm using Resque for heavy data processing on Heroku.

Using NewRelic, I see that my tasks use somthing like 15% of CPU share and 50mo RAM per instance.

I could process 5 jobs using only one dyno.

But I don't know how to do that.

I tried to use COUNT=5 in the procfile, but it does not seems to work. Moreover, ResqueRetry don't see failed job this way...

Anybody would know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things to your Procfile

First add the COUNT environment variable, then change the command from resque:work to resque:workers

Here is an example

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=10 COUNT=2 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:workers
```

I tested this solution on Heroku with only 1 resque dyno and saw the 2 jobs I sent being processed at once.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that if one of the jobs fails, it's not sent to the Retry queue by the Resque Retry. 
Moreover, one of the process could die without you noticing it.
It's clearly a bad practice :/